# flutter text width and height match parent

Tags: flutter, dart, height, width, flutter-widget

i want to achieve to set text width and height its parent size. this is what i tried but its not working:

```
Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Günlük",
                            style: TextStyle(color: getTextColor(0))),
                      )),
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Günlük",
                            style: TextStyle(color: getTextColor(0))),
                      )),
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Günlük",
                            style: TextStyle(color: getTextColor(0))),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

after i used this above code then text width and height is still wrap_content.(i investigated it by giving backgroundcolor to text). How to achieve it?

> ps :in the code block that i share the container width and height is
> infinite so if i try to surround it with `SizedBox.expand` its not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by Wrapping the `Text` widget inside a [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) with `fit: BoxFit.fill` so that it occupies all the available space.

```
Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildItem(Colors.red),
          buildItem(Colors.green),
          buildItem(Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

Widget buildItem(Color color) {
return Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    color: color,
    child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Text(
          "Günlük",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can use  SizedBox.expand() to achieve this

```
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: Text("Lorem ipsum"),
                  ),
                )
```

**PS:**
Hi, Ali, I understand what you are looking for but I think it is not possible because the text has no the width or height attributes, it is not something like container, column, etc., It can not expand like them. Even if you look at the view with debug paint open, you won't see the lines that envelop the Text. It looks it is not like TextView for native android.

If you want to achieve this you need to wrap it with a container like I did for the first item of the row. So instead of trying to make the “Text” match_parent, you need to deal with the wrapper of the Text.

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
//                  _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.purple, //here is the wrapper container
                          child: Text("Günlük",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
//                  _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Günlük",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white)),
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
//                  _onPagerTabItemClicked(0);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Günlük",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white)),
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: halil column içinde olduğundan ve widhler double.infinite oldugundan çalışmıyor. boş ekran geliyor. verdiği hata da BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

Comment: @AliGürelli , I updated my answer hope it helps or smbdy post an answer with a better solution

Comment: as i mentioned on the question, i want to expand width and height of text as parent's width and height. for example if parents width and height is 100 then the text width and height must be 100. but in your code that you share doesn't match with my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap every child with Expanded. Here is an example

```
Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("red");
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child:
                      Text("Günlük", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("abmer");},
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child:
                      Text("Günlük", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("green");},
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child:
                      Text("Günlük", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: if you set background color to text, then you will see that the text is still wrap_content. I have already tried it.